# Does $(a_n) \to 0$ imply $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} \frac {a_n}{n} < \infty$ is a convergent series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).
>   Does $(a_n) \to 0$ imply  $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} \frac {a_n}{n}$ is a convergent series?

It is simply a conjecture of mine that I couldn't disprove(or prove). 
I apologize if it has a simple counter-example.

Comment: Counterexample: $a_n = 1/\log n$